# Xamarin .NET C# AWS Cognito Identity Pool Login

Tags: .net, mobile, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, amazon-cognito

I created a Xamarin.Form, cross-platform mobile application in Visual Studio Community 2017.
I created a login page and want to integrate with AWS Identity Pool, but seems that I can't found an working example.

What I found:

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/sign-up-and-confirm-with-user-pools-using-csharp/) - I implemented the Login from here, but when I try to Log in I got an exception - but no compiling error, only some warnings:

```
Unhandled Exception: 
System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient..ctor' not found. occurred
```

[Here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/315809#Comment_315809) - but is User pool and I can't find CognitoUser and CognitoUserPool in [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html)

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/use-csharp-to-register-and-authenticate-with-amazon-cognito-user-pools/) - again can't find the mentioned classes

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, but here is an example of using AWS Cognito with Xamrin Forms:

https://github.com/curtisshipley/CognitoForms

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample application by using [AWS SDK for .NET](https://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/).

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples/CognitoIdentity